# Best (or any) way to use meteor helpers inside of Jade templates to select classes?

Tags: meteor, pug, meteor-blaze

I'm currently migrating an existing project from html templates in Meteor.js to Jade templates, and realized that some of my helper functions aren't working.   I've tried the handlebars style in the template, but when used to change class selectors it doesn't work.  There's also no error messages thrown on the client or the server.  I suspect that handlebars is called too long after the jade compilation to impact the jade selector.

```
template(name='header')
  header
    nav.navbar.navbar-inverse(role='navigation')
      .navbar-header
        button.navbar-toggle(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.nav-collapse')
          span.sr-only Toggle navigation
          span.icon-bar
          span.icon-bar
          span.icon-bar
        a.navbar-brand(href='/')
          img(src='/logo.png', alt='Company Name')
        a.navbar-brand(href='/') Company Name
      //- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling
      #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
        if hasValidUser
          ul.nav.navbar-nav
            if isInRole 'MajorDomo'
                +adminHeader

          ul.nav.navbar-nav
            li.dropdown +notifications
        #bs-example-navbar-collapse-1.collapse.navbar-collapse
          ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right
            +loginButtons
//- This does nothing, but gets called.
template(name='adminHeader')
  //- should call into the helper but doesn't 
  li.{{active 'faq'}}
    a(href='{{pathFor "faq"}}') FAQ
```

The helper never gets called:

```
# Coffeescript
Template.adminHeader.helpers
  "active": (path) ->
    console.log 'active called with: ', path
    if Router.current().route.name is path
        return "active"
```

So how would I dynamically set a class name in Jade, either using jade syntax with Meteor Blaze, or handlebars inside of Jade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it just like you did with `pathFor`, but assign the result to the `class` for the `li`:

```jade
template(name='adminHeader')
  li(class='{{active "faq"}}')
    a(href='{{pathFor "faq"}}') FAQ
```

This syntax will hopefully improve. Keep an eye on [issue #9](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade/issues/9).